# iconv routines get translated to libiconv_ names and fail to link on OS X

Tags: macos, iconv

I'm trying to build [Hercules](http://www.hercules-390.org) from the latest Subversion on Mac OS X 10.6. It uses the iconv library for character translations. The Hercules code uses iconv_open(), iconv(), and iconv_close(). Those routines are also present in the system library on 10.6, under those names. There's only one problem: I'm getting link failures for libiconv_open(), libiconv(), and libiconv_close().

I've hunted all over my system for where the names are being changed from iconv* to libiconv*, and not found a thing. Nothing in the Hercules code is doing this. Other folks are able to build fine on current OS X.

I'm missing something simple, but just can't find it. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this:

```
checking for iconv_open in -liconv... yes
checking for iconv... yes
....
Undefined symbols:
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _SDL_iconv_string in SDL_iconv.o
      _SDL_iconv_string in SDL_iconv.o
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _SDL_iconv in SDL_iconv.o
      _SDL_iconv_string in SDL_iconv.o
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _SDL_iconv_string in SDL_iconv.o
      _SDL_iconv_string in SDL_iconv.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/libSDL.la] Error 1
```

until I removed my two other copies in /opt/local and /usr/local (from Macports and a raw build of the GNU package). Then it worked.

Comment: That did it. I had removed the library previously, but was still tripping over the include that was left behind in /usr/local/include. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Beeing a bit late, in my case the following line did it (MacOS X 10.8.4):

```
CFLAGS='-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/' LDFLAGS='-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/ -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/' ./configure
```

I had to override the autotools LDFLAGS to tell the configure script to use the libraries shipped with the XCode SDK.